# jQuery TableSorter Plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins, tablesorter

Is it possible to disable the pagination (First, Previous, Next, last) links in the tablesorterpager plugin of jQuery. This is my code in jQuery

```
 jQuery('#mentor_engagement_report_table')
   .tablesorter({ debug: false, sortList: [[0, 0]], widgets: ['zebra'] })
   .tablesorterPager({container: jQuery("#pager"), positionFixed: false,size:10});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a fork of the [tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/) plugin on github. After reading this question, I added a new option to the pager plugin named `updateArrows` which when `true` it applies a class name, contained in the new `cssDisabled` option to the arrows. Here is the initialization code and a [demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-pager.html):

```
$("table")
  // initialize tablesorter
  .tablesorter()

  // initialize the pager plugin
  .tablesorterPager({
    // target the pager markup
    container: $("#pager"),
    // disabled class name to use
    cssDisabled : 'disabled',
    // apply disabled class name to the pager arrows when the rows at either extreme is visible
    updateArrows: true
  });
```

And here is some example of css used in the demo:

```
/*** css used when "updateArrows" option is true ***/
/* the pager itself gets a disabled class when the number of rows is less than the size */
#pager.disabled {
  display: none;
}
/* hide or fade out pager arrows when the first or last row is visible */
#pager img.disabled {
  /* visibility: hidden */
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only pagination if you use the [Pager Plugin](http://tablesorter.com/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js), if not, not a thing will have pager part...

if you would like just to hide the pager

after your javascript code add:

```
$(".pager").hide();
```

**Your question should be**, Why do i want to hie the pager area? if I only want to shown 10 rows, the data should only contain 10 rows ...

Comment: NO After I reach the last page I would like to hide the next pagination links and when we are in the first page I would like to hide the previous links. And when just a single page is displayed.. I would like to hide the whole thing.

Comment: Is there anyway form which I can get the number of pages

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you posted your whole code, and be more clear to what you want.

do you still want to select the row count per page?
then try this: http://jsfiddle.net/q66TA/

If you don't want anything from the pager, don't use it..

**Update:**
If you need the current page number and the total page count, you'll need to add this functionality to the plugin. There is a callback addon/patch available for this:
http://www.vinertech.com/patches/tblsorter.pager.cbk.patch

More on this: http://daveviner.blogspot.com/2009/12/jquery-tables-and-administrative.html

Answer (score 0):

The best way, and what we use on all our's that require a view all button, is to use the plugin itself's way of disabling it.

This is brought directly from their site http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-pager.html

The code used is real simple actually:

```
// Disable / Enable
    // **************
    $('.toggle').click(function(){
      var mode = /Disable/.test( $(this).text() );
      $('table').trigger( (mode ? 'disable' : 'enable') + '.pager');
      $(this).text( (mode ? 'Enable' : 'Disable') + ' Pager');
      return false;
    });
    $('table').bind('pagerChange', function(){
      // pager automatically enables when table is sorted.
      $('.toggle').text('Disable Pager');
    });

<button type="button" class="toggle">Disable Pager</button>
```